# Rear & front camera

Tags: camera

I'm looking for a product that combines the classic car camera (records front for insurance purposes) and rear camera (for reverse) with a single display.

Do you know if such product category exist?

Comment: If you have an Android smartphone and a dash mount, Daily Roads is free on the market and perfect for your front camera, might make finding a reversing only camera easier.

Comment: It won't play nice with the navigation app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are out there: http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/317970419/7_split_Screen_Reversing_monitor.html

google search car camera split screen.

Why do you need to watch where you are going via a camera and video? Ducking from bullets yet continuing to drive?

Comment: :-) Reverse camera for obvious reasons. Front camera (with recorder) for insurance purposes - if an accident happens and It's not my fault, I can prove it.